# Где расположены таблицы FAT файловой системы FAT32?

Tags: fat32

Ищу таблицу, содержащую в себе цепочки кластеров (cluster chains). Где на диске она может располагаться?

Comment: Много где она может располагаться. Начните с указания того, где и как вы ее ищете.

Comment: Я ищу её сразу после Bios Parameter Block до root кластера. А ищу по стартовому кластеру элемента

Comment: А у вас диск точно в fat32 отформатирован? У NTFS немного другой принцип хранения. FAT, насколько я помню, идёт от первого сектора нулевого цилиндра. Но сначала надо MBR посмотреть для тех информации по диску. Поищите книгу П. Нортона «Язык ассемблера для IBM PC», я по ней в своё время смотрел. Или ещё Абеля можно поискать, тоже ок вещь

Answer (score 5):

BPB  ([Bios Parameter Block](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_BIOS)) сам по себе и есть та таблица, с помощью которой можно выяснить, в каком именно секторе расположены таблицы FAT (в общем случае их может быть несколько; чаще всего их ровно две).

Вот поля BPB, которые могут вам понадобиться:

```
typedef struct
{
    ...
    // Количество зарезервированных секторов перед первой FAT // [14, 15]
    unsigned int reservedSectorCount;
    // Количество таблиц FAT // [16]
    unsigned char numberofFATs;

    ...
    // Количество скрытых секторов // [28, 31]
    unsigned long hiddenSectors;

    ...
    // Число секторов, занятых одной FAT // [36, 39]
    unsigned long FATsize_F32;

    ...
} BIOS_PARAMETER_BLOCK_STRUCTURE;
```

---

1. Логический адрес сектора первой таблицы FAT

Логический адрес сектора — адрес относительно начала логического раздела.
Логический адрес сектора *первой таблицы FAT* хранится в BPB в явном виде в поле

```
unsigned int reservedSectorCount; // Байты BPB: 14, 15
```

Так, для `unsigned char bpb[512]`, в котором `bpb[14] = 0x6E`, а `bpb[15] = 0x18`,
индекс логического сектора первой таблицы FAT `reservedSectorCount = 0x186E`.

---

2. Физический адрес сектора первой таблицы FAT

Физический адрес сектора — адрес относительно начала пространства адресов ячеек памяти, предоставленных физическим устройством.
Физический адрес сектора *первой таблицы FAT* можно вычислить, если прибавить к логическому значение поля

```
unsigned long hiddenSectors; // Байты BPB: 28, 29, 30, 31
```

которое хранит число секторов, предшествующих анализируемому логическому разделу.

Так, если `hiddenSectors = 0x000000E9`, то `0x000000E9` — физический адрес нулевого логического сектора (самого блока BPB), а физический адрес первой таблицы FAT

```
unsigned long phAddrFirstFAT = hiddenSectors + reservedSectorCount;
```

---

3. Адреса остальных таблиц FAT

Количество копий таблицы FAT логического раздела, и размер одной такой таблицы, также хранятся прямо в блоке BPB в полях

```
unsigned char numberofFATs; // Байты BPB: 16
unsigned long FATsize_F32; // Байты BPB: 36, 37, 38, 39
```

Так, если `numberofFATs = 0x02` — есть две копии таблиц FAT, следующие друг за другом,
Адрес второй копии таблицы FAT

```
unsigned long lAddrSecondFAT = lAddrFirstFAT + FATsize_F32;
unsigned long phAddrSecondFAT = phAddrFirstFAT + FATsize_F32;
```

---

Спецификация:
[Microsoft Extensible Firmware Initiative FAT32 File System Specification](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/fatgen103.doc)